# Unexplained issue with an ST Microelectronics STM32F100C6T6 MCU

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, error, firmware

I have been working on a rather sophisticated switch-mode power supply out of a Crown professional audio amplifier.

The STMicroelectronics STM32F100C6T6 is used on the power supply PCB for housekeeping. It is also responsible for turning on/off of the unit.

The microcontroller appears to be going into a state that makes the power indicator flash rapidly & the power supply becomes dysfunctional. I suspect that the microcontroller ends up in this state due to a fault on the class-D power amplifier PCB (there is communication between the two).

Once the microcontroller ends up in this state, even completely wiping the firmware and reprogramming it won't resume normal functionality; it continues to make the power indicator flash rapidly. I have only been able to resurrect the power supply by replacing the microcontroller and reprogramming it.

There is nothing wrong with the power supply outside of the microcontroller; the same thing has happened with two different power supplies.
I have come across other units in the past with the same issue, but was able to replace the microcontroller, reprogram, and resume full functionality.

What could be retaining this state inside the microcontroller even after erasing the flash and reprogramming it? There is nothing else wrong with the power supply except the microcontroller stuck in a funny state that can't be gotten rid of. Can the microcontroller retain something even after erasing the flash? Or does it get damaged somehow due to a fault elsewhere?

The MCU doesn't seem to monitor anything outside of the power supply, nothing on the faulty amp module. I'm not sure how a fault on the amp module gets reflected on the MCU except through the communication lines which shouldn't damage it.

[image]

Comment: The image is too low resolution to read.

Comment: Does anything come out of the serial data line on that debug port?

Comment: Not sure how to extract an image with better resolution out of a .pdf. Was using the snipping tool.

Comment: Will check the debug port tomorrow & let you know. It is close to midnight here in NZ. The MCU can’t be monitoring much except the state of the input in this state which is “Stand By”. It won’t turn on.

Comment: The MCU is functional, the “Heart Beat” LED is blinking but making the power LED blink rapidly for some unknown reason, does that even when the power supply was disconnected from the rest of the unit.

Comment: Can replace the MCU & reprogram it to get the power supply going, will be the third attempt in two weeks. Still risk ending up in the same situation due to the fault in the amp module.

Comment: So the question you're asking is: how can a mcu preserve some non-volatile state across reflashing... it doesn't have EEPROM, it doesn't have fuses... no non-volatile memory chip on the schematic... but when you reflash it, does it erase the whole flash, or just enough pages to write the firmware? Maybe the firmware assumes the mcu is virgin and all pages erased. You could try dumping the whole flash before and after it locks up to check. Or just erase the whole flash on a mcu that locked up.

Comment: Might also actually be damage to the MCU: for example, have a pin that is internally programmed to connect to the ADC, for voltage rail sensing. Expose pin to overvoltage, leading to damage to its VCC-side protection diode. from there on, ADC always signals that voltage rail is too high.

Comment: Did further experimentation with a functional power supply of the same type. The MCU appears to retain On/Off status of the PSU prior to removing power, even after global erase & reflash. It doesn't appear to regain "Virgin" status after a global erase & some information seem to get left behind. I'm using STMFlashLoader Demo program with a serial to USB interface. So my issue is a fault status not getting removed from the MCU, not a physical damage to it. At this stage not sure what more could be done.